# Flutter , Android app ffi package routes problem

Tags: android, flutter, arm64, ffi

We are developing and Flutter app using an FFI custom package.
When compiling everything the library compile is this structure.
opencv_ffi /
x86_64
x86
armeabi_v7a
arm64_v8a
but when create the apk under lib, use the same structure.
lib/
x86_64
x86
armeabi_v7a
arm64_v8a
Nevertheless, when the app trying to use the app. The code try to use lib/arm64 and not lib/arm64_v8a.

In my project the *pubspect.yaml*

```
name: opencv
description: A new Flutter opencv project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  opencv_ffi:
    path: ./packages/opencv_ffi
  go_router: ^11.1.3
  camera: ^0.10.5+5
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^23.1.40
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.3
  freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
  camera_platform_interface: ^2.5.2
  path: ^1.8.3
  before_after: ^3.0.0+1
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^23.1.40
  image: ^4.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  freezed: ^2.4.3

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

##In the Package opencv_ffi we have this files:

My  pubspec.yaml

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: io.abdelrahman.opencv_ffi
        pluginClass: OpencvFfiPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: OpencvFfiPlugin

ffigen:
  output: "lib/opencv_ffi_bindings_generated.dart"
  name: "OpencvFfiBindings"
  headers:
    entry-points:
      - "src/processing/processing.h"
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="io.abdelrahman.opencv_ffi">
</manifest>
```

my build.gradle

```
group 'io.abdelrahman.opencv_ffi'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace 'io.abdelrahman.opencv_ffi'
    }

    // Bumping the plugin compileSdkVersion requires all clients of this plugin
    // to bump the version in their app.
    compileSdkVersion 33

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
    }

    // // Bumping the plugin ndkVersion requires all clients of this plugin to bump
    // // the version in their app and to download a newer version of the NDK.
    // ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"

    // Invoke the shared CMake build with the Android Gradle Plugin.
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../src/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // cppFlags '-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++2a'
                // arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -frtti -stdlib=libc++ -v -g"

                arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF',
                        '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21',
                        '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
                        '-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON',
                        '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```